# Difference between PostMessage on windows 7 and windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, user32

I developed application that use PostMessage to simulate mouse click in another app.
I have screenshots of second app, i have coordinates for mouse click and i am simulate mouse click for second app. That all work fine on windows 7, but when i run it on windows 8 i am so confused:
screenshots of second app on win8 and win7 are the same, but when i emulate click by PostMessage, click occurred in different area. 
And i have two questions:
1) Why PostMessage work different on win8?
2) How it can be fixed?

EDIT:
For PostMessage lParam = ((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xffff)), where LoWord is Left and HiWord is Top coordinates

EDIT2:
More code

Step1

```
var hW = Win32.User32.FindWindow(null, "AppName");
```

Step2

```
MouseEngine.Click(hW, 100, 100);
```

where

```
public void Click(IntPtr hWnd, int left, int top)
    {
        // send mouse down
        User32.PostMessage(
            hWnd,
            User32.Message.WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
            0,
            User32.MakeLParam(left, top));
        // send mouse up
        User32.PostMessage(
            hWnd,
            User32.Message.WM_LBUTTONUP,
            0,
            User32.MakeLParam(left, top));
    }
```

where

```
public static int MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord)
{
    return ((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xffff));
}
```

Comment: Does your both machines have same screen resolution? same dpi settings etc?

Comment: No. But i tested it on machines with win7 and different screen resolution and it work fine.

Comment: Post your code which you claims to be working. For different screen resolution, you can translate it via simple math as [I shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23968643/2530848).

Comment: @MickyDuncan OP said "but when i emulate click by PostMessage, click occurred in different area" So it can't be the elevation problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Posted code how i calculate LParam

Comment: @galakt Please post _more_ code than just a simple description of arguments posted to a Win32 function

Comment: By your own admission, the PostMessage is working - the message gets posted. The issue is with the coordinates. Make sure your program is marked high DPI aware. Also, you should switch to UI automation. You can't use PostMessage to simulate input.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Posted more code. First app, that simulate click, is WPF. Second app, where click must be occurred, is not WPF app

Comment: @MickyDuncan OP said "click occurred in different area". Click work, the issue is with the coordinates

Comment: There's no difference between `PostMessage` on Win7 and Win8. Perhaps you are subject to DPI virtualization. What you should be asking yourself is why you are faking input in this way? Why don't you use automation, or even `SendInput`?

Comment: Please post an answer to your question now that you have the solution.

Comment: *"I developed application that use PostMessage to simulate mouse click in another app."* There's your error. Don't. Ever. It's wrong, for more than one reason. Use the right tool for the job: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). Added bonus: You don't need to calculate coordinates!

Comment: You got linked to from The Old New Thing for the bad idea of doing this via PostMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem occurred because on current machine with Win8.1 DPI default value 120(125%), while on all other machines is 96(100%)